# Javascript removeEventListener based on textbox input

Tags: javascript, html, input, textbox

I have a slider that updates a textbox input value in realtime using `addEventListener`.  What I need is for the textbox input to also update the slider when the textbox value is changed by the user.

Sample code,
HTML:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var textVal = document.getElementById("textVal");

function changeVal() {
  setInterval(function() {
    textVal.value = slider.value;
  }, 100);
}

function removeListener() {
  slider.removeEventListener("change", changeVal());
}

slider.addEventListener("change", changeVal());
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textVal" />
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="slider" class="slider" onfocus="removeListener()" />
```

JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/s8csgkmk/4/

Thanks!

Comment: `addEventListener`, and `removeEventListener` take a function reference. You however are currently executing the function instead of passing it

Answer (score 2):

- Bind the event `input` to your text field.
- Remove the `setInterval` and bind the `input` event.
- The `removeEventListener` seems unnecessary.

*You need to validate max, min, and numeric values*

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var textVal = document.getElementById("textVal");

function changeVal() {
  textVal.value = slider.value;
}

slider.addEventListener("input", changeVal);

textVal.addEventListener("input", function() {
  slider.value = this.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textVal" />
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="slider" class="slider"/>
```